# Docker Swarm Listen to ISP ips for Manager and worked node

Tags: docker, dns, docker-swarm, traefik, docker-network

I have a manager and a worker node in a docker swarm and two domains. One domain is pointing to the manager node (and is accepting traffic and working as intended) the other domain is pointed at the worker node but the traffic is not being routed through the swarm. What needs to be configured to get the worker nodes domain traffic into the swarm?

I was thinking it had to do with the ingress network but that doesn’t seem to be the case. The ingress network just allows for inter-node communication from what I can gather.

The swarm is setup with a traefik proxy that routes based on domain. The domain for the worker node is setup in the traefik proxy but it is not getting any of its traffic.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The problem I was running into was the swarm was receiving the traffic except the traefik proxy wasn't routing the traffic to the correct service.

I was able to debug it by looking at the logs in the main proxy then worked backwards.